# Object event communication in C++

Tags: c++

[image]

I have to design an  utility class which enables the event  communication between different objects. Every class should be derived from the util to use the framework it provides. In the diagram the restriction is like that whatever B publishes only A and C can receive whereas X and Y cant. It should be restricted in a group or a layer. when X publishes only B and y can receive. But when publishing publisher shouldn't know to whom it is publishing and same case for subscriber. It shouldn't know from whom it is subscribing. With a common publisher and subscriber method I can send event to any guy whoever is subscriber for it but I cant restrict it within a group. Here there is two group like A-B-C and B-X-Y. Again whatever changes should be done on utility, business logic shouldn't be changed which all the objects implements except util.

Any suggestion for the logic in the util class?

Comment: Inheritance means that A is a type of `util` class. If it isn't, you are abusing inheritance. BTW such questions are better suited for http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 1):

It looks like your desire is that instances of every class are allowed to communicate pub/sub with the class they derive from, plus all of their siblings (classes that derive from their parent class).

This is a very particular requirement, and particular requirements usually demand interesting solutions.

One solution would be to create a pub/sub class for every parent class.  Each class associates itself with its parent's class and its own (so that it can communicate with its siblings and all of its decedents respectively).

```
template <typename T>
struct PubSubSingleston
{
     static PubSubManager instance;
}

template <typename T>
PubSubManager PubSubSingleton<T>::instance;
```

A class can then associate itself with those pub-sub "layers".  Cleanest way to do that is probably with multiple inheritence, if you support it

```
template <typename ClassT, typename ParentT>
class PubSubHelper
{
    public:
        PubSubHelper()
        {
            PubSubSingleton<ClassT>::instance.associate(this);
            PubSubSingleton<ParrentT>::instance.associate(this);
        }

        void publish(const Message& inMessage)
        {
            PubSubSingleton<ClassT>::instance.publish(inMessage);
        }
};

class X
: public B
, PubSubHelper<X, B>
{ ... }
```

There are many other patterns (like CRTP) that work with this, but the fundamental technique is associating a class with some PubSub object associated with itself, and another associated with it's parent.

Comment: Thanks Cort..but I have the authority to change in util class to enable the communication and all objects only use the publish and subscribe method of util without knowing each other.

Answer (score 0):

```
typedef std::shadred_ptr<Child> ChildPtr;
//A and X inherit from Child

ChildPtr Util::AFactory()
{
    //In its constructor, A adds itself to its own subscribers set, 
    //which is really contained in Util
    return make_shared<A> (this->ASubscribersSetPtr);
}

ChildPtr Util::XFactory()
{
    //In its constructor, X adds itself to its own subscribers set, 
    //which is really contained in Util
    return make_shared<X> (this->XSubscribersSetPtr);
}

void Child::Publish()
{
    for(ChildPtr& indiv: SubscribersSetPtr)
    {
        if(indiv.get()!=this)
        {
            indiv->ReceiveMessage(this->message);
        }
    }
}
```